# Laravel Eager Loading Relation With Additional ->where()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

This is my relation method in my model:

```
public function relation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Table', 'table_2_id', 'table_2_id')->where('table_1_id', $this->table_1_id);
}
```

So, both the model above and `Table2` have the same column, but there is the possibility of many entries, so I want to then filter on a second column that is shared by both tables, `table_1_id`.

It seems to work perfectly on the command line, but when eager loading the relationship is empty.

If I remove the additional `->where()` from the relationship method then the eager loading works.

The way I am eager-loading is by doing

```
->with('relation.nestedRelation');
```

I've also tried

```
->with(['relation' => function ($q) {
    $q->with('nestedRelation');
}])
```

I've just tried adding it as an attribute to see if that helped but still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `whereColumn()` function :

```
->whereColumn('table_1.table_1_id', 'table_2.table_1_id')
```

Or you can use that :

```
public function filterRelation(){
     return $this->relation->where('table_1_id', $this->table_1_id);

}
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about that function, I get an unknown column error, I'm assuming this would need a join to work?

Comment: Yep you would have to do that, but if you don't want to, you can just use the edit I just made :) Then only catch is that you will first load the whole relation and not just row you want :(